# Bower not downloading angular-payments with response - No versions found in git:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, stripe-payments

Why can't I get this directly through bower install? I'm trying to follow a combination of https://www.airpair.com/javascript/integrating-stripe-into-angular-app and https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments but so far it's not going smoothly in regard to installing angular-payments.  What am I missing? I've tried different versions of:

bower install --save angular-payments#9643191f2359e18d543c4abf1581f91f6729445f
which is the latest hash. But I also tried it without the hash and also by declaring the latest version, 0.1.1.

Comment: I think that is a known issue on that repo. As I have read the version should be *. Which is also another issue. https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments/issues

Comment: How do you use it? I mean should I just copy and past the files or something?

Comment: Yea download the repo and take angular-payments and just add it that way. Easiest solution. Or look through the issue list and see if someone came up with a better way.

Comment: You can also try using * or latest for the version and see if that works

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob, I'm not sure what you mean by * or latest, could you elaborate?

Comment: it would be like: bower install angular-payments latest

Comment: thanks. tried that and * no dice. I suppose I'll copy, paste and hope for the best?

Comment: you can also tell bower to install right from the repo. I think the format is bower install <git url>#<git commit version>

Comment: but yea easiest way would be just to download it yourself

Comment: ya i copy and pasted each of the files labeled correctly from github however it says that it is not installed in my project though my .index correctly lists the directory and file

Comment: I copied and pasted it perfectly and added it to my index.html and app.js files as described in the tutorial but my app won't load, saying that angularPayments is not installed

Comment: Did you use or get this working in a project? I copied and pasted it but it says it's not there . . .

Comment: For some reason geolib 2.0.14 was breaking my bower install. I downloaded to an older version 2.0.9 and everything worked fine

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.